# Positive operator is bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory

> For a real Banach space $X$ let $A:X\rightarrow X^*$ be a positive operator in the sense that $(Ax)(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in X$. Show that $A$ is bounded.

I don't know how to do that, maybe it's an application of the closed graph theorem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is indeed an application of closed graph theorem. First, we take a sequence $\{x_n\}\subset X$  which converges to $x$ and such that $Ax_n\to \ell$, where $\ell\in X^*$. As the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded, we have $\langle Ax_n ,x_n\rangle\to \ell(x)$. For $y\in X$, we have
$$0\leq \langle Ax_n-Ay,x_n-y\rangle=\langle Ax_n,x_n\rangle-\langle Ay,x_n\rangle-\langle Ax_n,y\rangle+\langle Ay,y\rangle.$$
Taking the limit $\lim_{n\to +\infty}$, we get
$$0\leq \ell(x)-\langle A(y),x\rangle-\ell(y)+\langle A(y),y\rangle,$$
which gives
$$\ell(y-x)\leq \langle A(y),y-x\rangle.$$
Let $y=z+x$. Then
$$\ell(z)\leq \langle Az,z\rangle+\langle A(x),z\rangle.$$
Replacing $z$ by $az$, where $0<a$ and taking $a\to 0$, we get $\ell(z)\leq \langle A(x),z\rangle$. Replacing $z$ by $-z$, we get $\ell=Ax$.

Since $X$ and $X^*$ are Banach spaces, we conclude by closed graph theorem.

Comment: Dear Davide, I understand your answer was quite a while back, but I would like to invite you to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377620/proof-intuition-of-positive-linear-operators-are-bounded?noredirect=1#comment9149166_4377620 for an explanation to the intuition of this proof. Thank you!

Comment: @Mathematics_Beginner, take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4536539/630831

Answer (score 1):

We prove it by closed graph theorem. Assume $ x_n \rightarrow x $ in $ E $ and $ Tx_n \rightarrow t $ in $ E^* $, we show that $ t = Tx $, which is the same as $ \left\langle Tx-t, z\right\rangle, \forall z\in E $.

We use $ \lim $ to mean that we take limit with respect to $ n $.

Introducing $ P(x,y):=\left\langle Tx, y\right\rangle +\left\langle x,Ty\right\rangle  $ and using the fact $ P(x-ty,x-ty)\geq 0, \forall t \in \mathbb{R} $, it is not hard to show:
     $$ \left| P(x,y)\right| \leq\sqrt{P(x,x)\,P(y,y)} $$

The limit $ \lim P(x_n - x, x_n -x) $ exists and equals to zero for the assumption that we take and linearity of brackets. Therefore, $ \lim P(x_n-x, z) = 0, \forall z\in E $.

However, we can have the following calculation:
     $$
  \begin{aligned}
     \lim P(x_n-x,z)&=\lim \left\langle Tx_n-Tx,e\right\rangle +\lim \left\langle x_n - x, Tz\right\rangle  \\
   &=\lim \left\langle Tx_n-Tx,e\right\rangle = \left\langle t-Tx, z\right\rangle 
  \end{aligned}
 $$
     As so far, we have shown $\left\langle t-Tx, z\right\rangle =0  $ and hence finished the proof.