# Show that $T$ is continuous with $\langle x,T(x)\rangle\geq 0$

Tags: general-topology

> Suppose that $T$ is a linear application on a real-Hilbert space $E$ such that $\langle x,T(x)\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x$.
>
> Show that $T$ is continuous.

My attempt :

We have for all $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$
$$
0\le (T(x+\alpha y),x+\alpha y)=(Ty,y)\alpha^{2}+[(Tx,y)+(Ty,x)]\alpha+(Tx,x)
$$

The RHS is a quadratic polynomial in $\alpha$, so we know that the discriminant must be negative.

In this way we have $$x,y\in E,\ [(Tx,y)+(Ty,x)]^{2}\le 4(Tx,x)(Ty,y)\ $$

Now I am stuck I do not see how can I continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By identifying $E$ with its dual space (using the Riesz representation theorem), this becomes a special case of this question: [Positive operator is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216858/positive-operator-is-bounded)

Comment: I do not know closed graph theorem it's why I could not continue. So thank you very much!