# Proving continuity of a operator $T\colon E \to E'$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, closed-graph

Let be $E$ a Banach space over real numbers and $T\colon E \to E'$ linear such $T(x)(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in E$, prove T is continuous.

---

If $x_n\to x$ and $T(x_n)\to \phi\in E'$ then $T(x_n)(y)\to\phi(y)$ how to use $T(x)(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in E$?

Comment: If you haven't already noticed, it is sufficient to show that $T$ is closed

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Did you mean $graph(T)$?

Comment: Yes. "$T$ is a closed operator" means "$T$ has a closed graph" in my book

Comment: I'll work on this.

Comment: Any hint for conclusion, please?

Comment: I'll say something if I find the time.

Comment: By "$E$ a Banach space over real numbers" do you mean that $E$ is a (complete normed) vector space over $\mathbb R$? And presumably $E'$ is the dual space?

Comment: @Math1000 yes, I mean that

Answer (score -1):

This is well known exercise many times solved on MSE. Here is one [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216858/positive-operator-is-bounded).
$\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}\phantom{}$