# Proof intuition of Positive Linear Operators are Bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, intuition, constructive-mathematics

I got stuck on proving this exercise for quite a while and found the proof of this statement [Positive operator is bounded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216858/positive-operator-is-bounded) :

For a real Banach space $E$ let $T:E\rightarrow E'$ be a positive operator in the sense that $(Tx)(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in E$. Show that $T$ is bounded.

My question is, how exactly did we even come up with this proof construction at the first place? What I did was starting with $x_n \to x_0 \in E$ and $T(x_n) \to f \in E'$ and attempt to show $T(x_0) = f$. Namely, $T(x_0)(y) = f(y)$ for all $y \in E$. And then I literally just got stuck. The relation of the positiveness identity does not seem to "naturally" arise from this point (except from I could recognize that this might help us to show two-sided inequality). But how could we proceed beyond this point naturally? Or should I just take this proof as one of the proofs that does not have intuition at all and move on.

Comment: A heads up: There is no proof which "does not have intuition at all"!

Comment: Globally defined linear operators are either very inaccessible or continuous. Here you see that the algebraic property of positivity of the associated quadratic form is enough for continuity. The intuition is that it is very hard to find a globally defined (on a Banach space) unbounded operator that has any nice or useful properties. Every unbounded operator I could ever work with has a dense domain.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps writing the proof in a slightly different form might offer a better insight:

Define $P:X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb R$ as
$$ P(x,y) := T(x)(y) + T(y)(x)$$

Observe that this is a symmetric, bilinear form that is positive semi-definite. Thus Cauchy-Schwarz gives us
$$ |P(x,y)| \leq \sqrt{ P(x,x)\cdot
P(y,y)}$$
Our aim is to show $T$ is continuous. This means $T(x)(y)$ is continuous in both $x$ and $y$. We are already given that $T(x)(y)$ is continuous in $y$ for a fixed $x$. What about the reverse?

Given $x_n \rightarrow 0$ do we have $T(x_n)(y)\rightarrow 0$ for a fixed $y$? Note
$$|T(x_n)(y)+T(y)(x_n)|=|P(x_n,y)|\leq \sqrt{ P(x_n,x_n)\cdot
P(y,y)}$$
If we knew $P(x_n,x_n) \rightarrow 0$ then we could conclude $T(x_n)(y)\rightarrow 0$ for a fixed $y$.

But it is unclear how to do this. This is where the power of the closed graph theorem comes in.

> Closed Graph theorem: Let $L:X\rightarrow Y$ is a linear map between Banach spaces. If for all $x_n \rightarrow 0$ such that $L(x_n)\rightarrow y\in Y$ we have $y=0$ then $L$ is bounded and continuous.

Take $L=T$ and given $x_n\rightarrow 0$ such that $T(x_n)\rightarrow T_0$, observe that $$P(x_n,x_n) \rightarrow 2T_0(0)=0$$
Hence,  $T(x_n)(y)\rightarrow 0$ for any $y$ which means $T_0(y)=0$ for any $y$ and hence by closed graph theorem we get $T$ is continuous and bounded.